# How to Store Location information every 15 minutes in sqlite db & send to Server?

Tags: android, server, location, send

I need to work Location API for android where first the data is to be stored on Local Sqlite datbase in android itself each 15 minutes and then send it to a server, so that data can be tracked offline too.

Any suggestions, code or help is really appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You, can simply create a background service then implements a location listener. In that location listener, you can set the time interval in the `requestLocationUpdate` method to ping the GPS at particular time intervals. or you can use timertask to send gps at particular intervals
Here is a location manager instance:

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, timeinterval2, 0, locationListener);
```

You can send that location to the server from the service. You can also  send notifications to launch the app.

Comment: Ok i got it , but my problem is to fetch the data from Sqlite & send to server ! how can i do that!

Answer (score 1):

This question is many time asked in SO,

Use `Alarm Manager and Service` for this,

And go through this question

[How can i send latitude longitude of android device every 15minute to php web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440470/how-can-i-send-latitude-longitude-of-android-device-every-15minute-to-php-web-se) and [How to get gps coordinates every minute in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595099/how-to-get-gps-coordinates-every-minute-in-android)