# what should be the onLocationChanged content

Tags: android, android-studio, gps, android-pendingintent

I know that this question is asked many times in SO,and I've tried to follow 20 web page content..
[page 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595099/how-to-get-gps-coordinates-every-minute-in-android)
[page 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441736/how-to-store-location-information-every-15-minutes-in-sqlite-db-send-to-server)
[page 3](http://androidexample.com/Restful_Webservice_Call_And_Get_And_Parse_JSON_Data-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=101&aaid=123)
[page 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214825/how-to-run-application-in-background-in-android)
etc etc pages...

Basically my code [source](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/) is Androidhive.info

My issue is-- in log cat it is displaying the location but it is not saving in my database..

I have a php file at server and I am calling it by **httppost** on button click..My motto is

1.On button click it should send the location(this task completed)

2.App should run in background and send location details in time intervals(task pending)

As suggested in SO I've extended service but I am not using any alarm manager or job scheduler here

It is making my code clumsy..

So ***my question is*** what code should be written in onLocationchanged method so that it will send data to server whenever location is changed(program will run for every n minutes)

Code snippets::

1.GPSTracker.java

```
public class GPSTracker extends  Service implements LocationListener
{
statements;
}
```

2.some part in GPSTracker.java

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000,0, this); 
    Log.e("onLocationChanged",Double.toString(latitude));
    Log.e("onLocationChanged",Double.toString(longitude));
}
```

3.MainActivity.java

```
btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
        new LongOperation().execute();
    }
}
```

4.MainActivity.java

```
private class LongOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{
protected void onPreExecute()
{
}
 protected Void doInBackground(String... urls)
        {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> paramss = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latti", latti));
            paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longi", longi));

            try
            {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http:///insertData.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(paramss));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
                Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            try
            {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                        (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
                Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
            }

            try
            {
                JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                code=(json_data.getInt("code"));


                if(code==1)
                {
                    FLAG=1;
                }
                else
                {
                    FLAG=0;
                }
            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
            }
            return null;
          }
        }
```

Any suggestion would be of great help..

Kindly inform if any more code snippets are required

I am doing this project in Android studio

LOG::

```
02-02 10:52:22.180  15792-15792/com.example.mylocation E/onLocationChanged﹕ 17.3732771
02-02 10:52:22.180  15792-15792/com.example.mylocation E/onLocationChanged﹕ 78.5046526
02-02 10:52:24.050  15792-16248/com.example.mylocation E/pass 1﹕ connection success
02-02 10:52:24.070  15792-16248/com.example.mylocation E/pass 2﹕ connection success
02-02 10:53:22.130  15792-15792/com.example.mylocation E/onLocationChanged﹕ 17.3733159
02-02 10:53:22.130  15792-15792/com.example.mylocation E/onLocationChanged﹕ 78.5045958
02-02 10:54:22.070  15792-15792/com.example.mylocation E/onLocationChanged﹕ 17.3733133
02-02 10:54:22.070  15792-15792/com.example.mylocation E/onLocationChanged﹕ 78.5046106
02-02 10:55:22.120  15792-15792/com.example.mylocation E/onLocationChanged﹕ 17.373314
02-02 10:55:22.120  15792-15792/com.example.mylocation E/onLocationChanged﹕ 78.5046077
```

every minute it is giving me the location update in log..but this data is not sent to database

I've written http call in doInBackground() so the control is not passing to that method...it is never called again..

**EDIT 1**

when I used pending intent this screen is the output,even though my GPS settings are enabled

added code::

```
public Location getLocation()
    {
        try
        {
            intent = new Intent("com.example.dotweb.mylocation");
            pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),0, intent, 0);

            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext

            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled)
                {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,60000,0, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null)
                    {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null)
                    {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,60000,0, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }
```

neither `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,60000,0, this);`
 nor `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,60000,0, pi);` is doing the trick

[image: output]

Comment: For every n minutes we should call LongOperationdoInBackground();  how to do that

Comment: @ Abhishek Chaubey..I've added the log,..see,I have an update of every minute in log but not in db

Comment: You are requesting the location update inside of onLocationchanged(). Initially have you requested before. Once you have successfully requested, whenever there is location change as per your configuration then only the onLocationChanged() will gets called.

Comment: And one more suggestion instead of using Android API 1 Location Manager. Try with new FusedLocationProviderApi.

Comment: Exactly  @Vignesh...According to the time mentioned(60000) a call is going to onLocationChanged()...if you have a look at log it is displaying my location for every minute..but this data is not being sent to database...that is my headache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**onLocationChanged content.**

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        new LongOperation(latitude, longitude).execute();         
    }
```

`LongOperation` is an `AsyncTask class` which has `http call`

```
               try {
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("www.abc.com/kkk/ppp/nnn/update.php");

                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(paramss));
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        is = entity.getContent();
                        Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
                    }
```