# GPS location is not updating in server onLocationChange

Tags: android, gps

In GPS manager, I am getting the location update for every minutes in my Log.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,60000,0, this);
```

This line did the trick.

LOG:

```
02-03 11:32:33.045    6217-6217/com.example.mylocation E/onLocationChanged﹕ 17.3732643
02-03 11:32:33.045    6217-6217/com.example.mylocation E/onLocationChanged﹕ 78.5046052
02-03 11:33:33.245    6217-6217/com.example.mylocation E/onLocationChanged﹕ 17.3732721
02-03 11:33:33.245    6217-6217/com.example.mylocation E/onLocationChanged﹕ 78.5046024
02-03 11:34:33.315    6217-6217/com.example.mylocation E/onLocationChanged﹕ 17.3732627
02-03 11:34:33.315    6217-6217/com.example.mylocation E/onLocationChanged﹕ 78.5046052
02-03 11:35:33.215    6217-6217/com.example.mylocation E/onLocationChanged﹕ 17.3732669
02-03 11:35:33.215    6217-6217/com.example.mylocation E/onLocationChanged﹕ 78.5046055
02-03 11:36:33.145    6217-6217/com.example.mylocation E/onLocationChanged﹕ 17.3732575
02-03 11:36:33.145    6217-6217/com.example.mylocation E/onLocationChanged﹕ 78.504606
```

How to update this information in my database.

This service starts on a button click, so I've implemented Asynctask in which http call send data to database

This is happening only once, data is entered in database only once i.e. on button click, whenever onLocationChanged() is called updated data not sent to database

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 0, this);

    Log.e("onLocationChanged",Double.toString(latitude));
    Log.e("onLocationChanged", Double.toString(longitude));

}
```

Kindly help in solving this issue

Comment: Prathibha: i think you will need to call  method for inserting data in  `onLocationChanged` method which you are calling on Button click

Comment: ρяσѕρєя K...these both are in different activity...onLocationChanged is in GPSTracker class and Asyncktask which sends the data to server is in mainactivity class

Comment: Prathibha : then also separate logic for sending data to server in a separate class which you can use in both class's

Comment: And i read many post related to how to call AsynckTask from another activity..they are really very very complicated

Comment: ok...u mean create separate class which will just send data to server and invoke that class where ever needed

Comment: yes yes . and my suggestion is use IntentService for sending data to server instead of AsynckTask. because using `IntentService` first benefit is easy to use from any class just class startService method by sending data in intent. second benefit is if user close your app during sending data to server then `IntentService` automatically stop after completing task

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70107/discussion-between-prathibha-kirthi-and--k).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kevz it was not possible without your help...Thank you soooo much..

Here the answer goes:

Step 1::move AsyncTask to GpsTracker class

step 2::start the service in MainActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GPSTracker.class);
startService(intent);
```

step 3:: Use onStartCommand in GPSTracker.java

```
  @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        getLocation();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

It was not as simple as it look here..finally...COMPLETED..

Answer (score 1):

Your service starts on button click and location update is received in every one minute as you mentioned in your code,but the asynctask also starts on the button click and send the data to server,it completes it work and ends,it does not start again,so for sending data of every update to your server implement the asynctask in you `onLocationChanged(Location location)` method like this

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,60000,0, this);

    Log.e("onLocationChanged",Double.toString(latitude));
    Log.e("onLocationChanged", Double.toString(longitude));
    new yourAsynctask(parameters).execute();

}
```

Comment: i read some thing like over ride Asynctask..is it related to thst

Comment: you don't need to override the asyntask you need to extend the aysntask class and override its methods

Comment: sorry sorry...I mean use abstract class for Asynctask and then extend it

Comment: you will have many examples for it on internet just try to search and extend asynctask and do your work

Comment: if you have a look at this question..i've mentioned my code her  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262338/what-should-be-the-onlocationchanged-content

Comment: you have to call asynctask in onLocationChanged() as i told for every location update

Comment: ok..so the line you have added "new yourAsynctask(parameters).execute(); " you mean to use the same ASynctask class which is used on button click or shall i declare another ASynctask class within GPStracker class with the same functioning

Comment: in Gpstracker activity use ASynctask class which is declared in mainactivity with the same parameter...this is what u mean pramod??

Comment: the aysnctask in which you are sending request to server

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70107/discussion-between-prathibha-kirthi-and--k  pramod once enter this discussion

Comment: will you suggest how to achieve this task with a piece of code